# How to calculate the variance of this function of poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and $X_4$ are independent Poisson random variables with means $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_1 + \theta_2$ and $\theta_1 \theta_2$ respectively.

Now assume $\theta_1 =  \theta_2 = 1$. Calculate the mean and variance of

$$U = \frac{X_1 + X_2}{1+ X_3+X_4}$$

I know how to compute EU.

$EU = E(X_1 + X_2) E(\frac{1}{1+ X_3+X_4})$

I know $Y=X_3+X_4$ is Poisson(3). I know how to compute $E(\frac{1}{1+ Y})=\Sigma_{y=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+ y} \frac{3^y}{y!} e^{-3}$. It is easy to simplify. But I don't know how to use the same way to compute the variance.

I am stuck with the step $E(\frac{1}{(1+ Y)^2}) =\Sigma_{y=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+ y)^2} \frac{3^y}{y!} e^{-3} $

Comment: Empirically, the variance is just over $0.42$.  For your step at the end, [Wolfram Alpha suggests](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+1%2F%281%2Bn%29%5E2+*+3%5En%2Fn%21+*exp%28-3%29%2C+n%3D0+to+n%3Dinfinity) you may need the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)

Comment: @Henry so I guess there is no closed form of this variance?